# Evaluating trigonometric expressions in sympy

Tags: python, numpy, trigonometry, sympy

Using python 2.7 with PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3 + Anaconda distribution.

I have an input similar to :

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
f = cos(x)
print (f.subs(x, 25))
```

The output is `cos(25)`, . Is there a way to evaluate trigonometric identities such as sin/cos, at a certain angle ? I've tried `cos(degrees(x))`, but nothing differs. Am I missing some crucial part of documentation or there really isn't a way to do this ? Ty for your help :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perform a *numerical evaluation* using [function `N`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html#numerical-evaluation):

```
>>> from sympy import N, symbols, cos
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> f = cos(x)
>>> f.subs(x, 25)
cos(25)
>>> N(f.subs(x, 25)) # evaluate after substitution 
0.991202811863474
```

To make the computation in degrees, convert the angle to radians, using [`mpmath.radians`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.6.7/modules/mpmath/functions/trigonometric.html#radians), so the computation is performed on a *rad* value:

```
>>> import mpmath
>>> f.subs(x, mpmath.radians(25))
0.906307787036650
```

---

Importing with `*` (wildcard imports) isn't a very good idea. Imagine what happens if you equally did `from math import *`, then one of the `cos` functions from both modules will be out in the wild.

See the [PEP 8 guideline on imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Comment: You are right, kinda skipped the part about proper imports, this was the easy way around. Do you happen to know if there is a way to evaluate the expression based on the value in degrees ?

Comment: You mistyped the import for `mpmath`. Eventually, I imported it like this, `from mpmath import *`, but still cannot find a way to evaluate with degrees. Also, the evaluation `N(f.subs(x, 25))` returns a value that does not correspond to neither radians nor degrees

Comment: @borgmater That import works on sympy 1.0. And how do you mean *cannot find a way to evaluate with degrees*? That value corresponds to `cos(25)` in degrees.

Comment: You are right, I tried Wolfram Alpha couple of times and i got different values, now the values is correct. Thank you for your help :)